# Play Sound From String Arrays Swift

Tags: swift, audio, playing

I am trying to play a sound file for each image in a collection view, so if the user taps on an image, the user will hear the name of that image.  For example, if the user taps on the image of a cat, the user will hear the sound file, "cat".  I have created the collection view of images and a UITapGestureRecognizer was added to the cell.  The sound file is played in the imageTapped function at the very bottom of the code, but I do not know how to code this.  I don't know what to code after: if tap.state == .recognized, let imageView = tap.view as? UIImageView {  The current code in that function builds, but I do not hear a sound when I tap each image.  I would really appreciate any help.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

```
class FlashcardsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {

var animals = ["alligator", "bat", "bear", "beaver", "bird", "butterfly", "camel", "cat", "cheetah", "chicken"]

var bodyparts = ["arm", "ear", "eyes", "foot", "hair", "hand", "head", "leg", "mouth", "nose"]

var classroom = ["backpack", "blackboard", "book", "bookshelf", "calculator", "chair", "chalk", "chalkboard", "clock", "colored pencil"]

var clothes = ["belt", "boots", "coat", "dress", "hat", "jeans", "mittens", "pajamas", "pants", "scarf"]

var family = ["baby", "brother", "dad", "family", "grandma", "grandpa", "grandparents", "mom", "parents", "sister"]

var feelings = ["angry", "cold", "confused", "happy", "hot", "hurt", "sad", "scared", "sick", "tired"]

var food = ["apple", "bacon", "banana", "bean", "blackberry", "blueberry", "broccoli", "butter", "carrot", "cereal"]

var house = ["bathtub", "bed", "bowl", "couch", "cup", "dresser", "fridge", "lamp", "mirror", "plant"]

var transportation = ["ambulance", "bike", "boat", "bus", "car", "firetruck", "helicopter", "motorcycle", "police car", "plane"]

var verbs = ["brush your teeth", "carry", "clap", "color", "cook", "crawl", "cut", "dance", "draw", "drink"]

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(tap:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let arrays = [animals, bodyparts, classroom, clothes, family, feelings, food, house, transportation, verbs]
    let sectionArray = arrays[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
    return sectionArray.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let arrays = [animals, bodyparts, classroom, clothes, family, feelings, food, house, transportation, verbs]

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: arrays[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex][indexPath.row])

    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell

}

@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(_ sender: Any) {

    collectionView.reloadData()

}

func playSound(file: String?) {

    if let file = file {
        let musicFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)

        do{

            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicFile)

            audioPlayer.play()

        }catch{

        }
    }
}
@objc func imageTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    _ = tap.view as? UIImageView

    print("imageTapped")

    let arrays = [animals, bodyparts, classroom, clothes, family, feelings, food, house, transportation, verbs]
     let sectionArray = arrays[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

    if tap.state == .recognized, let imageView = tap.view as? UIImageView {
        for (image) in sectionArray {
            imageView.image = UIImage (named: image)
            if let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: image, ofType: "wav") {
                playSound(file: sound)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than you need to.

Firstly you keep creating your `arrays` multiple times, there is no need to do this. You could do something like this

```
var arrays =  [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // populate the array when your view loads
  arrays = [animals, bodyparts, classroom, clothes, family, feelings, food, house, transportation, verbs]

}
```

That means in your `cellForItemAt` you do not need to construct it there but you can access the `arrays` variable that you just created. For UICollectionView you should use `indexPath.item` instead of `indexPath.row`, `indexPath.row` is for UITableViews.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

  let array = arrays[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

  cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.item])

  cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

  return cell

}
```

You also do not need to use a gesture recogniser. UICollectionViews come with a function called `didSelectItemAt` this is called when you tap your cell. So you could do something like this. You may want to check if a file is already playing before you play the next file.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let array = arrays[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
  let filename = array[indexPath.item]
  if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "wav") {
    playSound(file: filepath)
  }
}
```

Also all those arrays that you are creating initially with the filenames, you should declare them as `let` unless you plan on changing the contents of them. It is more performant to use `let` than `var`. `var` should only be used if you plan on changing the value that is stored.

So change

```
var animals = ["alligator", "bat", "bear", "beaver", "bird", "butterfly", "camel", "cat", "cheetah", "chicken"]
```

to

```
let animals = ["alligator", "bat", "bear", "beaver", "bird", "butterfly", "camel", "cat", "cheetah", "chicken"]
```

Checkout Apple's documentation for more information about UICollectionViews https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: Andrew - this worked!  I cannot thank you enough!  I have been struggling with this for a few weeks now.  I started with a table view and then changed to a collection view and did not properly change the code.  I am a beginner coder and I always make code much more complicated than it needs to be.  Thank you for your clear directions.  I will study this code so I know what to do next time.  All the best to you and thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `playSound(file: String?)` in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Find the image from the selected cell